# how to make https request using php Http_Request2()

Tags: php, https, pear, http-request

i want to make a https request using pear http_request2($url) class.
i am able to make http request but not https. and the website facilitate both http and https. No prob with server responding to https.

```
    require 'HTTP/Request2.php';
    $url = 'https://collegedb2.ferryfair.com';
    $r = new Http_Request2($url);
    $r->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
    try {
        $response = $r->send();
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        $es = $exc->getTraceAsString();
        $ets=$exc->__toString();
        $egc=$exc->getCode();
        $egl=$exc->getLine();
        $egm=$exc->getMessage();
        $egt=$exc->getTrace();
        $response = null;
    }
    $page = $response->getBody();
    echo $page;
```

this is the error msg:

> `$egm=(string) Unable to connect to ssl://collegedb2.ferryfair.com:443. Error: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://collegedb2.ferryfair.com:443 (Unknown error)`

Comment: It seems the ssl certificate is not installed/configured correctly, when connecting i get the following error: ssl_error_rx_malformed_certificate (SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:unable to find public key parameters)

Comment: u tried connecting https://collegedb2.ferryfair.com ?? it is only available on our local network. ssl certificate on server got installed correctly. problem is with http_request2 class, it is unable to make https requests. openssl is enabled in php, checked in phpinfo()

Answer (score 7):

The comment to disable certificate verification was the key for me.

```
$request = new HTTP_Request2('https://someserver.com/somepath/something',
    HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);

$request->setConfig(array(
    'ssl_verify_peer'   => FALSE,
    'ssl_verify_host'   => FALSE
));
```

Comment: i got the target server certificate with me. I want to verify the certificate. if u succeed in verifying target please post it.

Comment: But always remember you're just suppressing the root of evil

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this problem. The fix (for me) was to use 'curl' as the adapter, for example :

```
$request = new Http_Request2('https://whatever');
$request->setAdapter('curl');
$response = $request->send();
```

See also the "SSL parameters" section on http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.config.php which says

> Peer verification is likely to fail if you don't explicitly provide ssl_cafile and/or ssl_capath, especially with Socket adapter.

Presumably curl knows where to find a local CA file to trust.

(PHP 5.4.38 with curl).

Comment: Ah, thanks for this one. Now I can stop worrying about rewriting all my requests with CURL. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_Request2 is absolutely able to make HTTPS requests. There is probably a deeper error, e.g. a custom SSL certificate that brings problems.

Install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and check which error you actually get with it. Post that back.

Comment: thanq cweiske, for a while i've skipped solving this issue. the target web application is using self signed ssl certificate. i think i should install the certificate in my web application. i donno how to. i googled it a lot about it, finally gave up. i need help here.

Comment: you can either disable certificate verification - see the options in http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.config.php - or install the public certificate of the authority (CA) that signed the self-signed certificate.

Comment: thanq. how abt using target web application's ssl certificate with ssl_local_cert or ssl_capath parameters. i didnt completely understand ssl_local_cert parameter, should it be given the file name of target web application's ssl certificate?

Comment: `require 'HTTP/Request2.php';
$url = 'https://collegedb2.ferryfair.com/lib/crap.html';
$r = new Http_Request2($url);
$r-> setConfig(array("ssl_verify_peer"=>TRUE,"ssl_local_cert"=>"$root/ssl/collegedb2.ferryfair.com.cert"));`
i am making this request from the same server..

Comment: i got the target server certificate with me. I want to verify the certificate. if u succeed in verifying target please post it.