# SSL_ERROR_SSL error:14090086:lib(20):func(144):reason(134) - PHP solution?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I get the error in the title when doing something like this:

```
$zurl = "https://api.zotero.org/something";
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
$r = new HTTP_Request2($zurl);
$r->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
$r->setHeader("Zotero-API-Version", "3");
$r->setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ".$apiKey);

$response = $r->send();
```

This [article](http://blaoism.blogspot.ro/2010/05/sslerrorssl-error14090086lib20func144re.html) seems to explain it to those who understand. I don't understand, unfortunately.

The article says it is (or might be) a problem with the certificate.

What can I do resolve this problem? (I am on a shared host.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get no answers to this one. I believe the reason might be that it is more common to use CURL directly (instead of the more high level Http_Request2 which I prefer). Two days ago @GingerDog posted a way to handle this:

```
// before send add:
$r-setAdapter("curl");
```

See [how to make https request using php Http_Request2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064362/how-to-make-https-request-using-php-http-request2)